# CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes, strange behavior?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, urlencode

I am trying to encode a URL, I've never done this before, so I'm confused when not getting the results expected.
I'm using `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` to do this, but whats returning looks nothing like any online URL encoders/decoders e.g.

```
-(void)urlEncodedString{


 NSString *str = @"\"Hi!! my name is John. \n What's your's?\"";

NSLog([(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,(CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR("!$&'()*+,-./:;=?@_~"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease]);


}
```

I was expecting something like:

> %5C%22Hi%21%21%20my%20name%20is%20John.%20%5Cn%20What%27s%20your%27s%3F%5C%22

But instead I'm getting:

> 2i2212yame                   0s2ohn3.786691E-27020A2hat                     º»åå2our                           0.0000002

That can't be normal. I've been searching and tried everything, the way I did it apparently should work.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the result as the first string to `NSLog` which expects a string with [formatting](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) which uses the percent signs. You are essentially filling the string with random data in memory in place of each % escape. To fix this log using an Objective-C object specifier:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,(CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR("!$&'()*+,-./:;=?@_~"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease]);
```

Comment: As a note the first parameter to `NSLog` or any other functions/methods expecting a formatting string (`printf`,`-[NSString stringWithFormat:]`) should be a literal.

Comment: Goodness, Thank you so much, I should have tried that, I'm back on track now.